# Error while installing Android Developer Tools in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

I have tried to install ADT using this [url](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/). But I'm getting below error. I can't install ADT.

```
An error occurred while installing the items
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=[R]com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 21.0.1.v201212060256-543035 --> [R]com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685, action=).
Failed to prepare partial IU: [R]com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685.
```

I'm working on ...

1. WIN 7 Computer. JDK 1.7.0 and JRE 7.
2. Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
3. Version: Indigo Service Release 2
4. Build id: 20120216-1857

How can I fix this error ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are new to Android development and Eclipse let's try the Google bundle:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Download the SDK, uncompress and code :D